# How to know the usage of user defined default constructor and user defined parametrised constructor java

Tags: java, constructor

I cannot grasp the usage of those constructors.

I understand that one is as follows:

```
public book(){
private string author;
private string title;
private int reference;
}
```

And a parametrised constructor is as follows:

```
public book( string author, string title, int reference){ 
}
```

However how would this be used in a main method?

Comment: The first snippet is not valid Java. The second one defines a method, not a constructor. Please google for "Java tutorial" and read the basics stuff.

Comment: This seems like something the manual can solve: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: I have changed them to constructors... I believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you can have a constructor:

1) You declare a no-parameter one

.

```
public class book
{
  string author;
  string title;
  int reference;
  public book() {
    // initialize member variables with default values
    // etc.
  }
}
```

2) You declare one with parameters

.

```
public class book
{
  string author;
  string title;
  int reference
  public book(string author, string title, int reference) {
    // initialize member variables based on parameters
    // etc.
  }
}
```

3) You let the compiler declare one for you -- this requires you do not declare one of your own.  In this case the member variables will be provided a default value based on their type (essentially their no-parameter constructor called)

You can mix options 1) and 2), but 3) is stand-alone (cannot mix it with any of the other two).  You can also have more than one constructors with parameters (the parameter types/numbers must be different)

An example use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String author = ...;
  String title = ...;
  int ref = ...;
  book book1 = new book(); // create book object calling no-parameter version
  book book2 = new book(author, title, ref); // create book object calling one-parameter
                                // (of type String) version
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pro grammatically, how to use them...

```
book b1 = new book();
book b2 = new book("My Title", "My Author", 0);
```

You call the first one to create an empty book.  There's probably setTitle(String title), setAuthor(String author) and setReference(int ref) methods, as well.  This would look like...

```
book b1 = new book();
// do stuff to get title author and reference
b1.setTitle(title);
b1.setAuthor(author);
b1.setReference(reference);
```

You'd call this one if you didn't have the title, author, and reference available when you were constructing the book instance.